# how to create a software application for a laravel project

Tags: mysql, laravel, inno-setup

first sorry for my poor English :)
I'm new to laravel, my professor asked me to create a Laravel+mysql application installer (.exe) for my laravel application I tried with desktop chrome and inno setup but that did not work.

Is there a way to create a software application for my laravel project to work on another computer without installing laravel and MySQL on that computer?

please can someone help me

Comment: thank you I will see it

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to deployment of web app like Laravel into different machines or operating system.

**Docker containerization is your best bet.**

With Docker, you can create  docker-compose or just an docker image of your web app and other dependencies.

These containers will then be able to run to any machine that has Docker in it.

*To give you an example these are my usual setup with a single Docker Compose project*

- My Web app runs in Production server (CentOS 7)
- Same web app runs on my local windows machine (Windows 10)
- Same web app runs on my Mac machine (Mac OS Big Sur)

No installations and configurations were needed, no Php's, Composer, Supervisor, and other related dependencies to run or install especially on local machines.

You just need patience and time to learn how these things work.

Here is a good intro for Docker containers.
https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container

Comment: I started with docker but when I run sail up an error display it    C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\management-app> ./vendor/bin/sail up
/bin/bash: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\management-app\vendor\bin\/../laravel/sail/bin/sail: No such file or directory  do you know what's the problem?